# Send Video file from Android to Arduino

Tags: android, arduino

From the below code I can convert a image file to byte array in my mobile app.But I cannot Convert a video file since **OutOfMemoryError** exception comes. I want to send a video file to a arduino board. Since I can send a string from android app to arduino, I am trying to send a video file like that. But it fails. I there any other solution to solve my problem?please help.

**Code for converting image to byte array**

```
package com.example.krishan.detectusbplugin;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Output/" +"My.mp4");
//        convertFileToByteArray(file);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(convertFileToByteArray(file)));
        try {
            System.out.write(convertFileToByteArray(file));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static byte[] convertFileToByteArray(File f) {
        byte[] byteArray = null;
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(f);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] b = new byte[1024 * 8];
            int bytesRead = 0;

            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(b)) != -1) {
                bos.write(b, 0, bytesRead);
            }

            byteArray = bos.toByteArray();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return byteArray;
    }
}
```

**Code for sending a string to arduino through usb cable**

```
package com.hariharan.arduinousb;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbDeviceConnection;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.felhr.usbserial.UsbSerialDevice;
import com.felhr.usbserial.UsbSerialInterface;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "com.hariharan.arduinousb.USB_PERMISSION";
    Button startButton, sendButton, clearButton, stopButton;
    TextView textView;
    EditText editText;
    UsbManager usbManager;
    UsbDevice device;
    UsbSerialDevice serialPort;
    UsbDeviceConnection connection;

    UsbSerialInterface.UsbReadCallback mCallback = new UsbSerialInterface.UsbReadCallback() { //Defining a Callback which triggers whenever data is read.
        @Override
        public void onReceivedData(byte[] arg0) {
            String data = null;
            try {
                data = new String(arg0, "UTF-8");
                data.concat("/n");
                tvAppend(textView, data);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    };
    private final BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() { //Broadcast Receiver to automatically start and stop the Serial connection.
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION)) {
                boolean granted = intent.getExtras().getBoolean(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                if (granted) {
                    connection = usbManager.openDevice(device);
                    serialPort = UsbSerialDevice.createUsbSerialDevice(device, connection);
                    if (serialPort != null) {
                        if (serialPort.open()) { //Set Serial Connection Parameters.
                            setUiEnabled(true);
                            serialPort.setBaudRate(9600);
                            serialPort.setDataBits(UsbSerialInterface.DATA_BITS_8);
                            serialPort.setStopBits(UsbSerialInterface.STOP_BITS_1);
                            serialPort.setParity(UsbSerialInterface.PARITY_NONE);
                            serialPort.setFlowControl(UsbSerialInterface.FLOW_CONTROL_OFF);
                            serialPort.read(mCallback);
                            tvAppend(textView, "Serial Connection Opened!\n");

                        } else {
                            Log.d("SERIAL", "PORT NOT OPEN");
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SERIAL , PORT NOT OPEN", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.d("SERIAL", "PORT IS NULLPORT IS NULL");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SERIAL , PORT IS NULL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d("SERIAL", "PERM NOT GRANTED");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SERIAL , PERM NOT GRANTED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } else if (intent.getAction().equals(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED)) {
                onClickStart(startButton);
            } else if (intent.getAction().equals(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED)) {
                onClickStop(stopButton);

            }
        }

        ;
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        usbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(this.USB_SERVICE);
        startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStart);
        sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);
        clearButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonClear);
        stopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStop);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        setUiEnabled(false);
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
        filter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED);
        filter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED);
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, filter);


    }

    public void setUiEnabled(boolean bool) {
        startButton.setEnabled(!bool);
        sendButton.setEnabled(bool);
        stopButton.setEnabled(bool);
        textView.setEnabled(bool);

    }

    public void onClickStart(View view) {

        HashMap<String, UsbDevice> usbDevices = usbManager.getDeviceList();
        if (!usbDevices.isEmpty()) {
            boolean keep = true;
            for (Map.Entry<String, UsbDevice> entry : usbDevices.entrySet()) {
                device = entry.getValue();
                int devicePID = device.getProductId();
                if (devicePID == 0x0043)//Arduino Product ID in Hexa
                {
                    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
                    usbManager.requestPermission(device, pi);
                    keep = false;
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "PID does not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    connection = null;
                    device = null;
                }

                if (!keep)
                    break;
            }
        }


    }

    public void onClickSend(View view) {
        String string = editText.getText().toString();
        serialPort.write(string.getBytes());
        tvAppend(textView, "\nData Sent : " + string + "\n");

    }

    public void onClickStop(View view) {
        setUiEnabled(false);
        serialPort.close();
        tvAppend(textView, "\nSerial Connection Closed! \n");

    }

    public void onClickClear(View view) {
        textView.setText(" ");
    }

    private void tvAppend(TextView tv, CharSequence text) {
        final TextView ftv = tv;
        final CharSequence ftext = text;

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ftv.append(ftext);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to read the whole video into memory? Read in a few bytes, call `serialPort.write()` for those few bytes, and repeat until done.

Comment: @CommonsWare how to read in a few bytes?

Comment: Um, `inputStream.read(b)`. It is in your code already.

Comment: @CommonsWare are you telling to call call `serialPort.write()` while  converting the video to bytes?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: @CommonsWare ok thanx I'll try